# Align & stack png images inside a bootstrap div with position:absolute

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

I am trying to align (and stack) some images inside a bootstrap grid.

For some reason, the images aligns to the window and not the grid.

I use position:absolute which work like this (http://www.w3schools.com/):

> "An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static. If no such element is found, the containing block is <html>"

Here is a jsfiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/sbE6t/

```
.rings img {
position:absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As you quoted, they will be absolutely positioned to the next non-static element. `If no such element is found, the containing block is <html>`.

Set position relative to the `img`'s parent:

```
.rings {
  // other styles
  position: relative;
}
```

[And it works](http://jsfiddle.net/sbE6t/1/)

Comment: Sometimes the solution is there and you don't see it :-) I thought .rings was already position:relative... Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

your wrapping element must be set to `position:relative`

```
.rings {
    overfow:hidden;
    height: 400px;
    background: #999;
    position:relative;
}
```